# error while trying to load libpjisipjni.so

Tags: android-ndk

I get this error while I'm trying to build my project.

failed can not load library "libstlport_shared.so"neede by libpjsipjni.so; caused by load_library(linker.cpp:746):library"libstlport_shared.so"not found